# What are Node.js + Faye Supported transport protocols

Tags: node.js, websocket, faye

I was looking into Faye and socket-IO, socket-IO degrades to websockets, flash sockets, JSONP and such, but what are all the supported transport methods faye supports? Does it support flashsockets? Also does it support Multi-channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[protocols folder on github](https://github.com/jcoglan/faye/tree/master/javascript/transport)

Websocket, xhr, JSONP.

It also has CORS which seems to be something to do with [Cross origin resource sharing](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)

No sign of flash sockets so far.

Comment: Thanks, wish it supported flash sockets too, would make things easier for degrading, Also any idea if faye supports multiple channels subscription?

Comment: @DregondRahl I presume you've read their documentation so I wouldn't know without digging through their source code. You can do the digging ;). Oh and if you dont need ruby just use socket.io or now

Answer (score 1):

Faye uses WebSocket, XMLHttpRequest, CORS and JSON-P in order of preference. Each client can subscribe to as many channels as you like.